# Having trouble with the cross-ratio. How to explicitly find a formula for $f$ from $(f(z), 1, -i, i)=\overline{(z, 1, -i, i)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

We're given that $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous.

I can see that $z$ and $f(z)$ are symmetric w.r.t. the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$. I think points symmetric to $z$ on $\mathbb{T}$ should be $\overline{z}$ so I conclude $f(z)=\overline{z}$.

How can I check if this is the right answer, and is there an alternate/more systematic way to find the answer to similar problems? I think if the cirle wasn't so simple I wouldn't be able to guess what the symmetric points should be (assuming I've done so correctly here)?

Edit: I just noticed in Conway's book (Functions of One Complex Variable - page 51) that symmetric point $z^{*}$ w.r.t. the circle $\Gamma=\{z\mid |z-a|=R\}$  satisfy $z^{*}=a+R^{2}(\overline{z}-\overline{a})^{-1}$. In our case this implies $f(z)=z^*=\frac{1}{\overline{z}}$. So my guess was wrong. But wait this $f$ is not continuous. Can someone please explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, for any three pairwise distinct point $a, b, c$ on the unit circle
$$
 (f(z), a, b, c) = \overline{(z, a, b, c)} \implies f(z) = \frac{1}{\bar z} \, ,
$$
which is the formula for the reflection at the unit circle.

*Proof:* We have
$$
 (z, a, b, c) = (\frac 1z, \frac 1a, \frac 1b, \frac 1c)
$$
because both LHS and RHS are Möbius transformations mapping $a, b, c$ to $1, 0, \infty$, respectively. It follows that
$$
(f(z), a, b, c) = \overline{(z, a, b, c)} 
= (\frac{1}{\bar z}, \frac{1}{\bar a}, \frac{1}{\bar b}, \frac{1}{\bar c}) = (\frac{1}{\bar z}, a, b, c)
$$
because the cross-ratio is a rational function of its arguments with real coefficients, so that we can “distribute” the complex conjugation over the four arguments, and using $a \bar a = b \bar b = c \bar c =1$ in the final step.

It follows that $f(z) =1/\bar z$.

Comment: @JohnSmith: $(w, a, b, c)$ is the image of $w$ under the (uniquely determined) Möbius transformation which maps $a, b, c$ to $1, 0, \infty$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, @Martin R. I got it. :)

Comment: I'm confused by something: how does writing $(1/\overline{z}, 1, -i, 1)$ make sense? That this is the image of the Mobius transformation taking $1$ to $1$ and $\infty$ implies it is not a bijection.

Comment: @JohnSmith: That was a typo, sorry!

Comment: @JohnSmith: I have rewritten the answer, it is more general now.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had inferred from your original answer. Thank you so much for your time/help.